# MySQL, Select all that don't have a sum in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
_id___|_description___
3433  | Apple-Pie
3699  | Strawberry-Pie
6952  | Banana-Pie
...
```

and

```
_cakeId__|_ ingredientCode _
3433     | SUGAR
3433     | APPLE
3433     | E_200_SRT_05
3433     | CREAM
3699     | SUGAR
3699     | STRABERRY
6952     | E_200_SRT_08
6952     | E_200_KJ_84
...
```

I now want to select all cakes (by id) that have **0 entries** in the ingredients table, **while ingredients starting with `E_` do not count**.

In my example above only the cake with id **6952** would be selected.

I tried several combinations of joins and subselect counts but I never got the right result

```
select 
    c.id
    t1.cntIngr
from 
    cakes c 

join (
    select 
        cakeId,
        count(ingredientCode) as cntIngr
    from 
        cake_ingredients    
    group by cakeId
    having ingredientCode not like 'E_%'

) as t1 on t1.cakeId = c.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3d375/2

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cakes c
LEFT JOIN cake_ingredients i
ON i.cakeId = c.id
  AND LEFT(i.ingredientCode,2)<>'E_'
WHERE i.cakeId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT description
FROM tab1
INNER JOIN (SELECT cakeId, COUNT(ingredientCode)
           FROM tab2
           WHERE ingredientCode NOT LIKE "E_%"
           GROUP BY cakeId
           HAVING COUNT(ingredientCode) = 0) AS tab2
ON tab1.id = tab2.cakeId
```

Comment: I guess your query brings opposite result than expected. Isn't it? probably you've meant `HAVING COUNT(ingredientCode) = 0` ?

Comment: and you missed `GROUP BY` when aggregate function `COUNT()` is in use :-)

Comment: I tried this code but somehow I got 0 results, i wanted to look for it later and tried version from Alex and this was result i tried to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

That's a NOT EXISTS query: You want all cakes for which no non-E ingredient exist:

```
select id
from cakes c
where not exists
(
  select *
  from cake_ingredients ci
  where ci.ingredientcode not like 'E\_%' escape '\'
  and ci.cakeId = c.id
);
```

Here is the same with NOT IN:

```
select id
from cakes
where id not in
(
  select cakeId
  from cake_ingredients
  where ingredientcode not like 'E\_%' escape '\'
);
```

(I usually prefer NOT IN over NOT EXISTS for its simplicity.)

Comment: Adding to this: Alex' query is fine. It is a trick query mimicking NOT EXISTS used on weak DBMS that don't handle NOT EXISTS and NOT IN so well. So you get a query less readable, but sometimes it is necessary to do this for performance reasons. (Besides, many people are so used to this trick that they do find it readable and NOT EXISTS doesn't even come to mind.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      id
      ,description
FROM cakes WHERE id NOT IN(
                  SELECT
                    cakeId 
                  FROM cake_ingredients
                  WHERE ingredientCode NOT LIKE 'E_%'
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f850/5